# String with byte array to byte

Tags: java

I have:

> String key = "0x64, 0xC, -90, 0x77, 0x2B, -113, 0xD, 0x69, -111, 0x76, 0x11, 0x35, -68, -110, -106, -81"

It is already bytes array in hex which was saved in shared preferences. I just need to put like below.

> byte[] input_key = new byte[]{ key }

Note that there are negative numbers.

Comment: You need to write a "mini parser" of sorts to do this. Good luck. --- But seriously, do you have an actual question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Comment: @BoristheSpider `Integer.valueOf(s, 16)` I doubt this will work. Look at the input: Base 10 and Hex is mixed.

Comment: What I would do: 1. Split the String by "," into String[]. 2. Declare byte[] of same size. 3. Iterate String[] and for each element n with index i : Decide if it is Hex or Base10 and parse it accordingly writing the result to byte[] at index i.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, it is a very hard form of code to understanding. AIDE wrote that something wrong with it. Sorry, but could you elaborate? And as mentioned below, it won't work with negative bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving the actual parsing for you to find out, this is what I described in comment:

```
String[] sNums = key.split(","); // Mind that the elements will still contain whitespace!

byte[] bNums = new byte[sNums.length];
for( int i = 0; i < bNums.length; i++ )
{
    if( sNums[i].trim().startsWith("0x") )
    {
       bNums[i] = [insert hex parsing here]
    }
    else
    {
       bNums[i] = [insert decimal parsing here]
    }
}
```

Not very efficient nor elegant, but will probably work if parsing is done right.

**Spoiler** : Boris in fact already spoiled the Hex-Parsing (point your mouse on yellow field vv )

> Integer.valueOf(s,16).byteValue()

Going from there, you surely can figure out decimal parsing.

Comment: I can't suggest edit (10 digits limit). Can you change regexp to ",\\s" and add hex part?

Comment: `sNums[i] = sNums[i].substring(2);
    bNums[i] = Integer.valueOf(sNums[i], 16).byteValue();`

Comment: Here is decimal parsing: `bNums[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(sNums[i]);`